# Two Routers - Two Subnets - One Switch

Tags: router

I have a question which I could not solve yet.
I have 1 Cisco Modem/Router which provides internet. Let's call it Router 1. I have 1 Linksys Router connected to Router 1. Let's call it Router 2. I have 1 unmanage Switch connected to Router 2 to provide Ethernet to other devices.

The only problem that I have is that the devices connected on Router 2 cannot see the devices connected on Router 1.

Router 1 has a subnet 192.168.0.X and Router 2 has a subnet 192.168.1.X.

1) If I am connected to Router 2 (with a 192.168.1.x ip address) I can get access to Router 1 gateway (admin panel) because I have configured it on Router 1 as the main the gateway.

2) For some reason my ISP does not allow me to change the Router 1 ip address to 192.168.1.X neither change it to act as a bridge instead Router.

Therefore, I don't know how to do to see devices connected in different subnets.
i.e: I have a server in 192.168.1.200 and the client that needs to get access to it is configured as 192.168.0.40.

Does it make sense?
Anyone can help me with it?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Have you tried connecting a ethernet port on router 2 to router 1 instead of the router 2 wan port?

Comment: @DavidPostill I didn't understand your suggestion. Would you mind please be more clear?
Do you mean instead connecting Router 1 to Router 2 WAN port, connect Router 1 to Router 2 any other LAN port?

Comment: Yes. Then router 2 should get a 192.168.0.x address and then put it in bridge mode.

Comment: My Router 2 does not support bridge mode. I did what you suggested but I guess more details are need it.

Comment: Like, should I disable DHCP in Router 2? How Router 2 should looks like? Which with IP Segment? 192.168.0.X? I still need the wifi works on Router 2 instead Router 1 (I don't care this wifi)

Comment: If router 2 does not support bridge mode you are out of luck I think.

Comment: You should follow the advice by @DavidPostill. The missing piece might be to disable the DHCP server option on Router 2, letting Router 1 do the job.